prediction = model.predict(email_features_array)
  prediction = model.predict(email_features_array)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'


i have already built and trained ML Model i only wanna use it through flask, but whenever it's about enter the mode.predict it gives me this issue
this is my code:
these are my imports
import pickle
import re
import string
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np  # Import NumPy

Load the pre-trained model

model = pickle.load(open('c:/Users/7rbe2/OneDrive/سطح المكتب/Main projects/Grad project/Phishward/PhishWarden/app/Python/logistic_regression_model.pkl', 'rb'))

# Initialize CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()

here are functions for cleaning
def remove_special_characters(word):
    return word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

def remove_stop_words(words):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    return [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]

def remove_hyperlink(word):
    return re.sub(r"http\S+", "", word)

def fit_count_vectorizer(text):
    # Clean and tokenize the text
    cleaned_text = remove_special_characters(text)
    cleaned_text = remove_hyperlink(cleaned_text)
    tokens = word_tokenize(cleaned_text)
    tokens = remove_stop_words(tokens)
    cleaned_text = ' '.join(tokens)
    return cleaned_text  # Return the cleaned text

here are the prediciton where th problem occurs
def predict():
    email_text ="hello world"
    cleaned_text = fit_count_vectorizer(email_text)
    cv.fit([cleaned_text])  # Fit CountVectorizer on the cleaned text
    email_features_array = cv.transform([cleaned_text])  # Use transform instead of fit_transform
    # Assume `model` is already defined and trained
    prediction = model.predict(email_features_array)

    # Apply the pre-trained model to predict the probability of the email being phishing
    probability = model.predict_proba(email_features_array)
    if prediction[0] == 1:
        result = 'Phishing'
        probability_score = probability[0][1] * 100
        print(result, probability_score)
    else:
        result = 'Legitimate'
        probability_score = probability[0][0] * 100
        print(result, probability_score)


# Example usage
predict()

i checked the type of my ML Model and got this:
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

, idk what i could do to solve this i tried almost every way possible

there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

the function predict() is missing an import opencv as cv and also model is not defined anywhere in the code.

the model variable is not defined anywhere in the code and is certainly not in the predict() function where it is called.
in fact, there is a comment:
# Assume `model` is already defined and trained

presumably it is in the global scope (poor practice) but omitted in the question.
so it looks like this should either:

be created inside the predict() function.
or
passed as an argument into the same function.

As a side note, the code is also missing cv which one might assume comes from the opencv module. In any regard, the code will not work without this being defined too...
